# AngularJS Performance: conditional inline classes/ng-if vs controller function;

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, angular-ng-if

I have controller with lots of conditional inline classes that helps change style(e.g. game in progress and completed game has different font colors) and ng-if  for conditional representation (e.g display short name vs full name if team consist of 2 people) of elements depending on the values of incoming data.
Example of ng-if:

```
<span ng-if="(isShortName && eventType == 'S')|| eventType == 'D'" ng-bind="player.shortName"></span>
<span ng-if="(!isShortName && eventType == 'S')" ng-bind="(player.firstName + ' ' + player.lastName)"></span>
```

Since the same layout is used multiple times (many events at the same time), I created directive that displays 1 event and then with ng-repeat apply this directive to multiple events from incoming data.

This event directive also have directives e.g to display the header of the table.

The amount of incoming of data is huge. With that many bindings I am noticing slowing in performance.

I am wondering from the view of best practices and performance improvements:

1) Is it better to have function in controller that would check what is the appropriate class to apply for the elements vs inline conditional classes?

2) Is it better to have function in controller that would check what appropriate name representation to use and return ready string vs inline ng-if?

3) It is better to remove nested directives to reduce amount of binding but end up having redundant code across pages? 
Thanks

Comment: `ng-if` is used to show\hide DOM. What do you mean when you say "ng-if that helps change style". If you can add come code it would be very helpful.

Comment: That was reference to ng-class - for style and representation for ng-if. If you dont want to help no need to down-vote the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you have detailed is still not very clear, but i can give you some generic advice that can be useful.

Firstly in Angular performance boils down to number of binding on the page and number of digest cycles that run over time.

To reduce the binding you should look at directives like `bindonce` (third-party) for angular 1.2.x or `::` symbol now available in Angular 1.3.x

`bindonce` and `::` are used to do setup once time data binding between the model and the view. This is useful for data that is not going to change after it has been bound.

Using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` also reduces the bindings as the DOM elements are not added to the view and no binding are setup.

Also look at `http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/` if you are rendering a large list.

With respect to reducing digest cycle look at this article from Brian Ford http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps, especially the section on digest cycle.

Last it does not make much difference if the binding expression is function or inline expression, as for Angular both are expressions and are evaluated against the current scope.